# A Battered Shield

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

*An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #39: Deep Down in the Dungeon 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6478/fortnightly-topic-challenge-39-deep-down-in-the-dungeon-1).*

---

Your party has defeated the previous riddles in the dungeon. The next room you enter is pitch dark - neither the light from your torches nor the firefly quickly conjured by the wizard penetrates the wall of darkness that starts two steps from the door. You guess that the room is huge (you have yet to encounter a small room in this place) and empty (at least nothing attacks you right away). On the floor near the door (which of course has closed as soon as you entered) is a battered shield. Looks like somebody took their last stand here...

[image]

What kind of monster awaits you here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The three texts in the shield

> correspond letter by letter. The single-underlined text is one sentence and double-underlined one is another. So the first visible words in the middle row correspond to "SHALL CONQUER" (the ending of the single-underlined sentence in Latin script).

From here, let's gather up all letters we know about the double-underlined line in the middle script.

> SOL?E ?H?S AND R??H?EOUS ... I'm going to guess this is "Solve this and righteous..."

Fill in the now-known corresponding letters in the outermost script.

> SOLVE THIS AND RIGHTEOUS GLOR? IS ?OURS -> "Solve this and righteous glory is yours"

Now we know all the letters and can figure out the text in the middle. The monster we're facing is...

> GRAVITY

Certainly a force to be reckoned with!